# JSON data via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am having JSON file with data
And I am calling it to fill in required info on the page

```
$.getJSON('/orders.json', function(data) {
    var entry = data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)];
    $('.product-name').html(entry.product_name);
    $('body').attr('id', entry.order_id);
});
```

Question. How I can scroll through all orders by click "Show next order" link without page reload.

I am trying to achieve the following functionality:

I open page I see random order (or just 1st in the list), then I click "Next" link and see the next order, but without page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var entry, orders;
$.getJSON('/orders.json', function(data) {
    orders = data;
    entry = Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length);
    displayOrder(entry);
    $("#button").on("click", function () {
        entry++;
        if (entry >= orders.length) {
            entry = 0;
        }
        displayOrder(entry);
    });
});

function displayOrder(num) {
    $('.product-name').html(orders[num].product_name);
    $('body').attr('id', orders[num].order_id);
}
```

Comment: you're going to have problems here because `#button` will get rebound each time the AJAX call is made.

Comment: @Alnitak the assumption is that the `$.getJSON` only needs to be called once

Answer (score 0):

Put *all* of the orders in the page in a common container, and use a class (e.g. `active`) combined with CSS style rules to indicate the one that should be visible.

In your button's `click` event handler, you can use:

```
$('#container > .active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
```

with the only complication being that once you've reached the last element in the list the code above will deactivate the last item, and leave none visible.

You can test `$('#container > .active').length` to find out if there's any active items, and either disable the button, or leave the last item active, or go back to the start of the list, e.g.:

```
$('#next').on('click', function() {
    $('#container > .active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

    if ($('#container > .active').next().length === 0) {
        $('#next').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/hDyCL/

Comment: I need to use JSON, so this simple approach will not work in my case.

Comment: my code is just a demo of how to handle the clicks - nothing stopping you from reading your json and filling the container with content in your `$.getJSON` callback.